# Creating a magento component from scratch

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am trying to create a magento shopping cart module but things arent working out. Here is my steps

I first create a xml in the app etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then  I create my folder in the local pool

```
/local/mywebwow/AdvancedCatalog/
```

In that folder I put the following files

```
/Block/AdvanceCatalog.php
/controllers/indexController.php
/etc/config.xml
```

I put the following in the block

### AdvancedCatalog.php

```
<?php
class mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block_Advancedcatalog extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getHelloworld()
    {
        return 'Hello world';
    }
}
```

### indexController.php

```
<?php
class mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

### config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </myweboww_AdvancedCatalog>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <AdvancedCatalog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog</module>
                    <frontName>advancedcatalog</frontName>
                </args>
            </AdvancedCatalog>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <AdvancedCatalog>
                    <file>advancedcatalog.xml</file>
                </AdvancedCatalog>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <AdvancedCatalog>
                <class>mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block</class>
            </AdvancedCatalog>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <AdvancedCatalog>
                <class>mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Helper</class>
            </AdvancedCatalog>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

when i type in website.com/index.php/advancedcatalog/

I get a 404. no page found.

[EDIT]

I changed the block class from MyWebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block_AdvancedCatalog to MyWebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block_Advancedcatalog

I added advancedcatalog.xml it looks like the following...

### advancedcatalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <advancedcatalog_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="advancedcatalog/advancedcatalog" name="advancedcatalog" template="advancedcatalog/helloworld.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </advancedcatalog_index_index>
</layout>
```

then there is the following which I already had

```
/template/advancedcatalog/helloworld.phtml
```

### helloworld.phtml

```
<h2><?php echo $this->getHelloworld(); ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to fix, hopefully one will get you moving:

1. Move your controller from `indexController.php` to `IndexController.php`. On case-sensitive systems, this very well could cause the controller not to be found.
2. Have you defined a layout file? (e.g. advancedcatalog.xml). Your file defines `advancecatalog.xml`, which seems like it might be a typo, though it could work if you defined that file.
3. Do you have any views defined? `loadLayout` will try to load a layout handle for the page and render blocks accordingly. This is where you'll have to specify your `advancedcatalog/advancedcatalog` block. If you do have a layout and templates, please post those.
4. Don't use camelcase for the block name, it will confuse Magento. The block will need to be defined as `advancedcatalog/advancedcatalog`, but that will resolve to `mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block_Advancedcatalog` (note no second cap). This will be an issue.

Fix those and see if it starts working, let me know if you still have trouble.

Thanks,
Joe

---

You don't necessarily need a model unless you are invoking one. As for #4, it's up to you whether you want to use mixed case on that one. In your config file, you specified the prefix for `AdvancedCatalog` blocks to be `mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block`, so the mixed case shouldn't be a problem. Conversely, though, you may want the tag inside of blocks to be lowercased, so that when you invoke your models you can stick w/ the existing Magento convention of lowercase. Do this:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <advancedcatalog>
            <class>mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block</class>
        </advancedcatalog>
    </blocks>
....
```

Comment: Hi, I greatly appreciate your response. I dont get much responses on magento but I appreciate it cause i need it. I edited the code. I changed advancecatalog.xml to advancedcatalog.xml

Comment: Im looking at number 4. You said use advancecatalog/advancedcatalog. Are you refering to the block type within the layout ?? Also is the mywebwow fine or should I make it Mywebwow_AdvancedCatalog_Block_Advancatalog

Comment: Thanks for your help alot. I think you pointed me in a good direction. The key to getting this fixed was that there is only suppose to be 1 uppercase letter in the module.

Comment: Also I did not create a model which I believe is essential.

Answer (score 0):

@numerical25: Also clean cache to get desired output (i.e.,) Go to system->cache management then flush magento cache..